# Show entries for every item even if record doesn't exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. The first table is a list of lots - table name `lot`. There are a total of 3 lots that are managed by three people and the fields are: lot.lotID, lot.LotName

Every day, these lots will collect eggs, but sometimes, the people collecting will forget to make the entry at the end of the day. These entries go into a table called `deposit`. This table has deposit.DepID, deposit.DepDate, deposit.LotID and deposit.DepAmount

I need to list every lot each day and get each deposit amount. If there is none made, instead of not displaying a record, it should show that the record is a NULL value or 0. For instance if no entry is inserted into the database for lot 2 on 2018-10-11, I should see this if I query two days' worth of data:

```
LotID | LotName | Date | DepAmount
1 | Sarah | 2018-10-09 | 67
2 | Dave | 2018-10-09 | 84
3 | Mike | 2018-10-09 | 78
1 | Sarah | 2018-10-10 | 100
2 | Dave | 2018-10-10 | 0
3 | Mike | 2018-10-10 | 49
```

Alternately, it is okay if lot 2 on 10-10 says:

```
2 | Dave | 2018-10-10 | {null}
```

Can someone give me a bit of direction here? It seems like it would be insanely simple, but I can't find much on the subject. Thanks in advance!!

PS - Here are the two tables:
lot:

```
LotID   Name
1   Jim
2   Mary
3   Jeff
4   Steve
5   Clinton
6   George
7   Jennifer
```

and deposit:

```
DepDate  DepAmount   UserID   LotID
2018-10-09 07:09:13 150.00      1
2018-10-09 07:21:22 345.00      2
2018-10-09 19:18:33 283.00      3
2018-10-09 19:37:51 100.00      4
2018-10-09 14:11:47 357.00  8   5
2018-10-09 14:21:43 5324.00 8   6
2018-10-09 14:27:46 564.50  8   7
2018-10-10 14:32:29 3543.75 6   2
2018-10-10 23:12:40 234.00  10  3
2018-10-10 07:09:13 52.00       1
2018-10-11 07:09:13 234.00      3
2018-10-10 07:09:13 764.00      4
2018-10-10 07:09:13 123.00      6
2018-10-10 07:09:13 764.00      7
```

Comment: The second table, from the text, "These entries go into a table called deposit. This table has deposit.DepID, deposit.DepDate, deposit.LotID and deposit.DepAmount" The expected result is that I posted. There is a table there... didn't look at my post?

Comment: @JD Dggn just put your all tables with some data  and out put what you want than any one can helps

Comment: @JDDggn what if there is no deposit done by anyone at a particular date. Would you still like to show entry for that date, and showing null for everyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky problem as a straight [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) will not work due to a person having values for dates other than the one which has no value in `deposit`. So we need to first [`CROSS JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) `lot` with a list of all the dates in `deposit` to get a set of all people and all dates i.e.

```
SELECT l.LotId, l.LotName, dt.Date
FROM lot l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DepDate AS Date
            FROM deposit) dt
```

Output:

```
LotId   LotName     Date    
1       Sarah       2018-10-09
2       Dave        2018-10-09
3       Mike        2018-10-09
1       Sarah       2018-10-10
2       Dave        2018-10-10
3       Mike        2018-10-10
```

Then we can `LEFT JOIN` this result with the `deposit` table to get our list of deposits for each day, using [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to convert `NULL` values to 0:

```
SELECT l.LotId, l.LotName, dt.Date, COALESCE(d.DepAmount, 0) AS DepAmount
FROM lot l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DepDate AS Date
            FROM deposit) dt
LEFT JOIN deposit d ON d.LotId = l.lotId AND d.DepDate = dt.Date
ORDER BY Date, l.LotId
```

Output:

```
LotId   LotName     Date        DepAmount
1       Sarah       2018-10-09  67
2       Dave        2018-10-09  84
3       Mike        2018-10-09  78
1       Sarah       2018-10-10  100
2       Dave        2018-10-10  0
3       Mike        2018-10-10  49
```